# How to convert event-based communication into async/await using asyncio.Future

Tags: python-asyncio

I'm trying to expose an event-based communication as a coroutine. Here is an example:

```
class Terminal:

    async def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        future = loop.create_future()

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run_cmd, args=future)
        t.start()

        return await future

    def run_cmd(self, future):
        time.sleep(3)  # imitating doing something
        future.set_result(1)
```

But when I run it like this:

```
async def main():
    t = Terminal()
    result = await t.start()
    print(result)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I get the following error: RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future

Is it possible to achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. One is that the `args` argument to the `Thread` constructor requires a sequence or iterable, so you need to write wrap the argument in a container, e.g. `args=(future,)`. Since `future` is iterable (for technical reasons unrelated to this use case), `args=future` is not immediately rejected, but leads to the misleading error later down the line.

The other issue is that asyncio objects aren't thread-safe, so you cannot just call `future.set_result` from another thread. This causes the test program to hang even after fixing the first issue. The correct way to resolve the future from another thread is through the [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#asyncio-multithreading) method on the event loop:

```py
class Terminal:
    async def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        future = loop.create_future()
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.run_cmd, args=(loop, future,))
        t.start()
        return await future

    def run_cmd(self, loop, future):
        time.sleep(3)
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(future.set_result, 1)
```

If your thread is really just calling a blocking function whose result you're interested in, consider using [`run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) instead of manually spawning threads:

```py
class Terminal:
    async def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        return await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.run_cmd)

    # Executed in a different thread; `run_in_executor` submits the
    # callable to a thread pool, suspends the awaiting coroutine until
    # it's done, and transfers the result/exception back to asyncio.
    def run_cmd(self):
        time.sleep(3)
        return 1
```